# How to prevent users from reading files but the webserver should still be able to read

Tags: permissions, webserver, lighttpd

I have a lighttpd test server on my testing machine with 2 users they all have there own folder with a public folder for the webserver in it, now I want to prevent that the other user can read the stuff of the other user, but the webserver should still have access. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chown the respective folders to a group of which the webserver is a member, but both users are not. Lets assume, the server is running as user www-server, the users are called user1 and user2. Then, if there isn't a suitable group yet (usually there is), create a new one and add the webserver user to it:

```
sudo addgroup www-private
sudo adduser www-server www-private
```

Now, for each user the private folder should be chowned so that the owning user is the respective user, and the owning group is the one of the webserver:

```
sudo chown user1:www-private /path/to/folder/of/user1
sudo chown user2:www-private /path/to/folder/of/user2
```

The permissions can now be set accordingly, so that the user has write access to his own folder, the webserver has read access and any other user has no access:

```
sudo chmod 750 /path/to/folder/of/user1 /path/to/folder/of/user2
```

If I remember correctly, this should give you the desired result.

Comment: i have the same idea as you have. i think this will work

Comment: This certainly takes care of the problem from the operating system point of view. Stupid question: What is to stop each user from pointing their browser to the other user's file and reading it this way?

Comment: with some access rules provided by the webserver ^^

Comment: I don't know much about lighthttpd, but a quick search on the web hinted towards something like this: 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/lighttpd-setup-a-password-protected-directory-directories.html